# Simple Sharepoint 2013 Java Script in Content Editor

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2013

I would like to embed HTML in a SharePoint 2013 that creates two hyper-links using JavaScript.

As an example I'd like the follow page with two links:

*Click Here* for Pages. *Click Here* for Documents

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://example.com/Pages">Click Here</a> for pages.<a href="http://example.com/Documents">Click Here</a> for Documents.
</body>
</html>
```

The reason I want javascript is I will ultimately extend this to dynamically generate the URLs with different links.

I have zero experience in JavaScript but learn best from example. I have done a lot of investigation but cannot find a simple example like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to assign each link an ID so that you can assign them to variables in the JavaScript, and then modify the href property of each link. From there you can either hard code them or load via AJAX. Here is how to hard code them.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*These variables allow you to reference and manipulate the specfic DOM elements 
          (ie. the a tags we gave ID's of link1 and link2)*/
        var link1 = document.getElementById('link1'),
            link2 = document.getElementById('link2');

            link1.href = 'http://example.com/Pages';
            link2.href = 'http://example.com/Documents';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="link1" href="">Click Here</a> for pages.<a id="link2" href="">Click Here</a> for Documents.
</body>
```

EDIT: I threw the script into a script tag inside of the HTML. Not sure if that's what you were asking but this is how to integrate them together. Here is a live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/h1b4a3gb/

Comment: As i'm new to this would you be able to link the two code snippets together so i can see how they would work together?

Comment: Great. Exactly what i wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answer my original question to run this within a SharePoint Content Editor Web part I used the following code.

```
<a id="link1">Click Here</a> for pages.<a id="link2">Click Here</a> for Documents. 
<script type="text/javascript">
        var link1 = document.getElementById("link1"),
            link2 = document.getElementById("link2");

        link1.href = "http://example.com/Pages";
        link2.href = "http://example.com/Documents";
</script>
```

The key difference here is the script must appear after the link definitions otherwise it will not work as the DOM object doesn't exist.